# Upgrading from PHP 5.5 to Php 7

Tags: php

**PHP 5.5** is Retiring in 11 days so what would be the best stable option to upgrade **PHP 5.6** or **PHP 7**?

Comment: of course to PHP 7

Comment: Depends. Does your code rely on features that might have been removed in newer php versions? Like the `mysql_*` functions in php 7.

Comment: but on official site they said php 5.6 is more stable yet

Comment: yes but i am going to change it to mysqli now

Comment: was it necessary to downvote it? @jeroen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Noon friend,

As per the link http://php.net/supported-versions.php Active Support Until was till 10 Jul 2016 and   Security Support Until - 10 Jul 2016.

that doesn't mean you can not use it. You can use it but php community doesn't do any fixes on that. Lots of current websites still using php 5.x versions.

I suggest use php 5.6. PHP 5.6 has better support in almost all framework and extension availability.  I have tried with php 7 but still lots of library and frameworks doesn't fully support PHP 7. Aslo when you tried to install extension on Windows like WAMP and XAMPP with PHP 7 it's hard to get it. I have tried with mbstring but after long research I got it which is used by Magento 2 and Symfony2.x framework so I suggest use PHP 5.6.

Hope this answer will work for you. :)

Comment: Thnx @kapil now i got my confusion bit clear. still i didn't give a try to php 7 bcz i am upgrading to php 5.6

Comment: Welcome  Shahroz,   Are you  using XAMPP or WAMP over windows ? if yes you can install latest XAMPP who support PHP 7 in separate directory and use it as well.